# Anaconda: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: The specified module could not be found. Nothing works

Tags: anaconda

I tried executing conda update conda, and afterward, none of the commands worked. Every time I tried to execute any command, I kept getting the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: The specified module could not be found.
```

I then attempted to reinstall libffi and python using Conda, but the issue persisted. Here's the error message I received after trying to install libffi:

`conda install libffi` and `conda install python` 
still nothing works.

```
(base) C:\Users\eyabe>conda install libffi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 36, in main_subshell
    from ..base.context import context
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ..common._os.linux import linux_get_libc_version
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\common\_os\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .windows import get_free_space_on_windows as get_free_space
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\common\_os\windows.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ctypes import (
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 109, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(main, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 389, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 20, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 52, in handle_exception
    from .exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .models.channel import Channel
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\models\channel.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ..base.context import Context, context
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ..common._os.linux import linux_get_libc_version
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\common\_os\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .windows import get_free_space_on_windows as get_free_space
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\common\_os\windows.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ctypes import (
  File "C:\Users\eyabe\anaconda3\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed whi
le importing _ctypes: The specified module could not be found.
```